# Escaping mysql search string php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a question regarding best practices involving a search form with PHP/MySql

Consider the following:

- A search form to search for book titles
- A jQuery / AJAX request to "auto-suggest" titles
- Need to escape and how?

The mysql user which connects to the database only has the `SELECT` privilege at the moment but I might add the `INSERT` privilege in the future (thus potential for injections).

The search form is simple, such as this:

```
<form id="search" method="GET" action="/search/">
  <input type="text" value="" id="s" name="s" />
</form>
```

The form sends via GET to `search.php?s=Search Query`. Once there, the PHP file is something like the following:

```
<?php

  $s = $_GET['s']; // the search request

  $search = new Search($s); // creates new search object and sends the $s query

  echo $search->output;  // returns results

?>
```

My Search class has the following:

```
class Search {

  // Database stuff omitted

 $stmt->bindParam(':search', $this->query, PDO::PARAM_STR)
 $stmt->execute;
 $res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 $this->output = $res;

}
```

My sql query is this: `SELECT booktitle FROM books WHERE booktitle LIKE '%:search%'`

What problems might I get into? Do you have any suggestions as to what needs to be escaped and where? Do you see potential problems with my setup? Concerns such as sql injections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters are automatically escaped in prepared PDO statements, you're doing it right.

Just be noticed that you don't need the quotes in your query:

```
$stmt = $myPDO->prepare("SELECT booktitle FROM books WHERE booktitle LIKE :search");
$stmt->bindParam(':search', "%".$this->query."%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

Or even simpler:

```
$stmt = $myPDO->prepare("SELECT booktitle FROM books WHERE booktitle LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute( array("%".$this->query."%") );
```

More info: [Are PDO statements automatically escaped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548059/are-pdo-statements-automatically-escaped)